# In how many ways can a 15-asset portfolio be constructed?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a portfolio with 15 assets, each with individual weight w(i). The weights are integers between 0 and 100, the sum of all weights are 100.

In how many ways can this portfolio be constructed?

Thanks,
Steffen

Comment: Is it the problem of finding 15 vars that a1+a2+...+a15=100?

Comment: Yes, that would be a way of looking at it

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29).

Comment: "For any pair of positive integers n and k, the number of distinct n-tuples of positive integers whose sum is k is given by the binomial coefficient {k-1 \ n-1}". That was exactly was I was looking for, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finding 15 variables with sum 100 is like splitting 100 identical ball into 15 different containers. One way of doing this is to place 14 buffer between that 100 balls. It is equivalent to place that 100 identical balls and 14 identical buffers in any order, which is:

$114!/(100!*14!)$

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect. I was looking at theorem 1 of Stars and Bars (link above). Should have looked at theorem 2. Thanks a lot!